# Error when attempting to import a node module into NuxtJS TypeScript (ES2018)

Tags: typescript, npm, nuxt.js

I am attempting to import the chess.js module like so:

`import Chess from 'chess.js';`

This gives me the following error when loading the app locally:

`require() of ES Module .../app/node_modules/chess.js/chess.js from .../app/node_modules/vue-server-renderer/build.dev.js not supported. Instead change the require of chess.js in .../app/node_modules/vue-server-renderer/build.dev.js to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.`

Well I'm already using an import statement, not require. I've tried playing around with different ways to import the module but nothing is working. I understand this is caused by using TypeScript when creating the NuxtJS app. I'm currently trying to import the chess.js module into a .js file, not a .ts file, and something is getting mistranslated here.

Any ideas?

This is my tsconfig:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2018",
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "lib": [
      "ESNext",
      "ESNext.AsyncIterable",
      "DOM"
    ],
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "~/*": [
        "./*"
      ],
      "@/*": [
        "./*"
      ]
    },
    "types": [
      "@nuxt/types",
      "@nuxtjs/axios",
      "@types/node"
    ]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    ".nuxt",
    "dist"
  ]
}
```

**UPDATE** Converting the .js file to .ts and running 'npm i --save-dev @types/chess.js' did the trick. But I'm still wondering if there's a way to get the original JS script to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using the `import()` function with JavaScript.

You need to follow these steps to accomplish it.

1. Remove the following line from `package.json`.

   ```json
   {
     "type": "module"
   }
   ```
2. Change your `import` statement to the below. Make sure you are using the LTS version of Node.js, as older versions don't support top-level `await`!

   ```js
   const chess = await import("chess.js");
   ```

This should remove the error, while also allowing you to use JavaScript.

Comment: I also found that nuxt has a config option to transpile certain modules.

Comment: @hipsterstomper69 indeed!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with a module I built.

The solution came from here: https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/concepts/esm#es-modules

I added the NPM package to the nuxt.config as follows:

```js
//nuxt.config.ts

export default defineNuxtConfig({
    build: {
        transpile: ['@module/name'],
    }
})
```